# The method launchAbout(null) is undefined for the type new View.OnClickListener(){}

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, undefined

The method launchAbout(null) is undefined for the type new View.OnClickListener(){}

```
package org.example.asteroides;

import android.app.Activity;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.view.Menu;

import android.view.View;

import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

import android.widget.Button;

public class Asteroides extends Activity {
private Button bAbout;

         @Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

             super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

             setContentView(R.layout.main);

             bAbout =(Button) findViewById(R.id.Button03);

             bAbout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                        public void onClick(View view) {

                             launchAbout(null);


                        }

                 });

         }

@Override

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.asteroides, menu);
    return true;
}


}
```

Comment: Where is the `launchAbout` method declared?

Answer (score 0):

you can fix it like this:

```
          bAbout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(View view) {

                         launchAbout(null);

                    }
                    private void launchAbout(Object object){
                     ....
                    }

             });
```

or define a method named launchAbout  in the class Asteroides

Answer (score 0):

If this is your complete code, it's pretty obvious to get that error because method `launchAbout` is not declared.

If this is not your complete code, please edit your answer.